# Highcharts with JSON double quotes

Tags: json, highcharts, double, quotes

I found a post here: [Trying to push data to a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614564/trying-to-push-data-to-a-json-array) and am facing the same JSON double quotes issue with highcharts gantt charts.

From that post it is not clear how it was solved. Can you give me some more details and sample code?

Comment: It's probably easier if you post some of your code here. Start with the code which generates your JSON.

Comment: So you need to use double quotes in json, so i'm not sure where the problem is ?

Comment: Highchart expects the data in the following format:
var tasks = [{
    name: 'Sleep',
    intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
        from: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 0),
        to: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 6)
    }, {
        from: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 22),
        to: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 24)
    }]
}]

Comment: but when i generate the json using my code it has got double quotes
all over like given below so the chart is not displaying.
var tasks = [{
    "name": "Sleep",
    "intervals": [{ // From-To pairs
        "from": "Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        "to": "Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 6)"
    }, {
        "from": Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 22)",
        "to": "Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 24)"
    }]
}]

Comment: Please post the code that was used to generate that information.

Comment: hi, i was able to pin point the issue. The issue is with Date.UTC. The following data works var tasks = [{"name":"AA20101101CECFU","color":"Red","intervals":[{"from":Date.UTC(2013, 02, 12, 0),"to":Date.UTC(2013, 02, 20, 1),label:"AA20101101CECFU"}]}]; So the problem is how to generate the value for "from" and "to" that is how to convert a date in Java to the format "from":Date.UTC(2013,02,12,0) ? @MatthewKremer the code i am referring to is http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/ i am trying to generate the json data dynamically, that is the only difference.

Comment: Correct, that code works though, we want to see the code that is generating the JSON data.

Comment: ok seems like i am able to solve it, i was using string for date, let me try to convert it into UTC Date format and see. I shall update you tomorrow since it is really late here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to push data to a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614564/trying-to-push-data-to-a-json-array)

Answer (score -1):

```
$str="[";
$result =  $conn->query("SELECT name , value AS y FROM table_name ");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $str.="{name: '".$row['name']."', y: ".$row['y']."},";
}
$str.="]";
```